# Как добавить скорость и задержку загрузки

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Помогите что и куда вставить чтоб можно было выставлять скорость и задержку по времени

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){

    if ( jQuery(".more-button").is('.infinite-scroll-wrapper')){

//      var templatePaged = templatePaged || 1;

        var infinite_scroll = {
            loading:{
                msgText:"",
                finishedMsg:"<em>No additional posts.</em>",
//              img:templateURL+"/js/infinite-scroll/ajax-loader.gif"
                img:templateURL+"/img/preloader.GIF"
            },
            state: {currPage: templatePaged},
            nextSelector:".more-button a",
            navSelector:".more-button",
            itemSelector:"article.post",
            contentSelector:"section.content",
            debug:false,
            behavior:"twitter",
            callback:"",
            pathParse: function (path, currentPage) {
                path = path.split("/page/")[0]+"/page/";
                return [path, ''];
            }

        };
        jQuery( infinite_scroll.contentSelector ).infinitescroll(
            infinite_scroll,
            function(newElements, data, url) {
                $('.infinite-scroll-wrapper a').find('span').hide();
                jQuery('body').addClass('infinite-scrolled').attr('data-infinite-page',data.state.currPage);
                if (pag instanceof Paginator) {
                    pag.drawPages = function(){
                        var percentFromLeft = this.html.scrollThumb.xPos/(this.html.table.offsetWidth);
                        var cellFirstValue = Math.round(percentFromLeft * this.inputData.pagesTotal);
                        var html = "";
                        if(cellFirstValue < 1){
                            cellFirstValue = 1;
                            this.html.scrollThumb.xPos = 0;
                            this.moveScrollThumb();
                        } else if(cellFirstValue >= this.inputData.pagesTotal - this.inputData.pagesSpan) {
                            cellFirstValue = this.inputData.pagesTotal - this.inputData.pagesSpan + 1;
                            this.html.scrollThumb.xPos = this.html.table.offsetWidth - this.html.scrollThumb.offsetWidth;
                            this.moveScrollThumb();
                        }

                        var infiniteScrolled = (' ' + document.body.className + ' ').indexOf(' ' + 'infinite-scrolled' + ' ') > -1;
                        var infinitePaged = document.body.getAttribute("data-infinite-page");

                        for(var i=0; i<this.html.tdsPages.length; i++){
                            var cellCurrentValue = cellFirstValue + i;
                            if(cellCurrentValue == this.inputData.pageCurrent){
                                html = "<span>" + "<strong>" + cellCurrentValue + "</strong>" + "</span>";
                            } else if ( cellCurrentValue >= templatePaged && cellCurrentValue <= infinitePaged && infiniteScrolled ) {
                                html = "<span>" + "<strong>" + cellCurrentValue + "</strong>" + "</span>";
                            } else {
                                html = "<span>" + "<a href='" + this.inputData.baseUrl + cellCurrentValue + this.inputData.afterBase + "'>" + cellCurrentValue + "</a>" + "</span>";
                            }
                            this.html.tdsPages[i].innerHTML = html;
                        }
                    }
                    jQuery(".paginator tr:first-child td span a").each(function(){
                        if (jQuery(this).html() == data.state.currPage) {
                            jQuery(this).parent().html('<strong>'+jQuery(this).html()+'</strong>');
                        }
                    });
                }

                if (jQuery(newElements).hasClass('stop_infinite_scroll')) {
                    jQuery(this).infinitescroll('destroy');
                    jQuery(infinite_scroll.navSelector).hide();
                }
                eval(infinite_scroll.callback);
            }
        );
    }
```

Comment: Помочь _что-то_ _куда-то_ вставить?

Comment: Хотя бы код прокомментируй что-ли, что он делает, за что отвечает, мы же не потомки Ванги

Comment: этот код делает подгрузку записей на блоге по кнопке. но когда нажимаешь на кнопку записи загружаются мгновенно, а мне нужно чтоб через пару секунд т.к. на кнопке вращается картинка прелоадер.

Comment: попробуй `setTimeout (function () { тут ваш скрипт}, 2000); // время в мс`, куда именно вставить не подскажу, так как я не знаю как происходит инициализация твоей функции